# Medusa JS 401 responses in the admin panel on server, works fine in localhost

Tags: node.js, nginx, admin, digital-ocean, medusajs

I have deployed medusa js on on a digital ocean droplet with Nginx.
It works fine on the local host when I run npm start and access the admin UI at http://localhost:9000/app
but when I try to do the same on the server with the same env variables it just redirects me back to the login page.
it gives 401 errors like this[image]

here are details of one of the request

[image]

here are my evs

```
DATABASE_TYPE=postgres
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://.....
JWT_SECRET=bVra...
COOKIE_SECRET=J31X...
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
YARN_PRODUCTION=false
NODE_ENV=production
```

also when I try to fetch normal store API like https://api.everydayoptics.in/store/products it works fine:

[image]

I am using the default admin panel on the same domain, so it should not be a CORS error.
Here is my Nginx config I just left the root routes(everydayoptics.in and [www.everydayoptics.in](http://www.everydayoptics.in/)) to show the default Nginx page for now and use the API subdomain (api.everydayoptics.in) for the backend and admin panel.

```
server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name everydayoptics.in www.everydayoptics.in api.everydayoptics.in;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.everydayoptics.in;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://everydayoptics.in$request_uri;
}

server {

    server_name everydayoptics.in;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}

server {
    server_name api.everydayoptics.in;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/everydayoptics.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this was an Nginx config issue, adding the following lines in the location of the last server block fixed my problem.

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:443;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```